# Animating a container view code

Tags: ios, uiview

I have an app with two UIViews in a IB ViewController. Each of these is a container view having two UIImageViews.

I use Core Motion gravity to move these views as the device is tipped. There are also two UIImageViews in the IB view.

I am trying to animate the UIImageViews inside the container views.  However, when the animation happens, it takes place immediately instead of taking place over 5 seconds that I specify in the annimation.

I have tried to animate the container view and the UIImageViews but the same thing occurs.

Any ideas?

This is my code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         [self.myView setFrame:0,0,11,23self.myView2 setFrame:0,0,11,23))];
                         )];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished
```

This changes the size of the container view Myview and myview2.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0
```

Buw that you want to achieve is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:5
```